# Set C11 as default Language in Clion

Tags: c, default, clion

I'm studying C at the university and I just downloaded Clion; How can I change the default language so that every project I create will be ready to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the version of Clion you will either see the `CMakeLists.txt` contain something like

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
```

or for recent EAP builds

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

Simply change the variables and flags to the correct ones for C.

There's currently no way (that I know of) to make it use C language as default for new projects. You must manually edit the project `CMakeLists.txt` file.

---

With recent versions of CLion you can now create C projects as well, making this answer somewhat obsolete.

Comment: The flags for C is `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `-std=c11`

Comment: dang. was looking forever what the problem was :D